# fix second word position html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Very new to JavaScript, HTML hence not sure how to change this piece of code.

I have 3 words, say `x`, `y`, `z` - the length of these words can vary. I want `y` to start at a fixed position after `x`. Below is what I am doing.

```
var text = '';
text += '<div style="float: left; font-size: 0.2em; padding-left: 5px">' + x + ' ms</div>'; }
text += '<div style="float: center; font-size: 0.8em; padding-left: 5px; text-align: center">';
text += y;
text += '<div style="float: right; font-size: 1.0em; padding-right: 5px">';
text += z;
text += '</div>';
```

This adjusts `y` to be in center - moving it left if the length of `z` is a bit large.
*i.e.*, what I need is this:

```
x   y   z
x   y zzz
```

and not this:

```
x   y   z
x  y  zzz
```

Any help will be appreciated. Also some good resource to learn JavaScript, HTML fast.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would just use a table with right text-align.

Comment: Thanks maraca, will it be possible to achieve it with DIVs?

Comment: the text goes inside a <td> tag and hence would prefer a div, <td> inside a <td> would not look that good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use fixed widths, inline-blocks and `text-align: right` on on all DIVs.

```css
.a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a">x</div>
  <div class="a">y</div>
  <div class="a">z</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a">x</div>
  <div class="a">y</div>
  <div class="a">zzz</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a">x</div>
  <div class="a">yy</div>
  <div class="a">z</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Johannes, but his unfortunately doesn't seem to be working. I have added "text-align:right, width:25px" to my div and now the result is:
 x\n
 y\n
 z\n i.e., all the words on a new line.

Comment: Did you erase the "float" properties? (you shouldn't) Or instead, you can add `display: inline-block;`

Comment: I have tried multiple combinations of float, display and width but cannot all of them cannot seem to be on the same line :(. Also, text-align: right seems to push 'y' right- I'll like to be in centre but all the 'y's should start from the same point. Thank you!

Comment: I added an example snippet to my answer